# discrete family of sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ is a discrete family of close subsets of $X$.
Then is it true that, any two members of $\mathcal{F}$ are disdoint??

[A family $\mathcal{F}$ is said to be discrete if for $x$ in $X$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ which meets at most one member of the family $\mathcal{F}$.]

[ If $\mathcal{F}$ is a discrete family having finite number of members, then it is easy to check that every two member of the family $\mathcal{F}$ are pairwise disjoint.]

Comment: What is your proof for the case when $F$ is finite? Do you really use the finiteness at all?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose two of the sets $A,B$ of $\mathcal F$ intersect, with $x\in A\cap B$. It is impossible to find an open set containing $x$ which meets at most one member of $\mathcal F$